# How I can generate a Horizontal Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I’m have a problem/question regarding how I can generate a Horizontal Crystal report in next format:

1. I have a object “sale” which have next elements/parameters:
   a.    Ariel;
   b.    Tide;
   c.    Persil; d.    Colgate; e.    Orbit; f.    Aqua Fresh; … h.    SaleDate;
2. The object have elements which can be grouped:
   a.    Arial + Tide + Persil = Detergents
   b.    Colgate + Orbet + Aqua Fresh = ... Dental stuff (something like this).
3. Accordantly to Crystal I will get a report which will be generate a in vertical direction like:
   www.constructor.md/FL/tmp/Table1.JPG

I need it to be generated in Horizontal format something like this:
[IMG](http://www.constructor.md/FL/tmp/Table2.JPG)

Also I tried the Cross-Table, I was not able to get what I need.

**PLS!!! advice me, where and what to set in Design to be able to prepare this kind of report.
THX in advance!!**

Comment: You might be looking for a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Cross Tab reports. Don't accept this as an answer. (this is trivial)

Comment: I think I can't use Cross-Tab because I dont have a cross. 
I have just array of one type object and I want to display it in horizontal way.
Take a look on this: www.constructor.md/FL/tmp/Table3.JPG

Comment: @Sairus: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "I have just array of one type object and I want to display it in horizontal way"? Where does your data come from?

Comment: I have a C# project, in this project I have a object which contains some parameters. So for daily report I'm displaying this object + some formulas. But now I need to display a monthly report, so as input I have ArrayList of my Object.
I hope my explanations are understandably.

Regard,
Sairus

Comment: @Sairus: So the report doesn't use a database? I am sorry, I don't know how to use c# objects inside a crystal report for data source. Can you put the c# code to help me understand what you are trying to do & if it can be done?

Comment: I know how to use the object us Data Source. You can look on this object as a single table which have columns = object parameters.
object name = table name: sale
Parameters/Columns:
sale.date
sale.profit
sale.balance
sale.Trades_Prod1
sale.Trades_Prod2
...
sale.Rates_Prod1
sale.Rates_Prod2
...
This example is accordingly to table 3:
www.constructor.md/FL/tmp/Table3.JPG

THX a lot for your partisipation & trying to help me!

Comment: I am not sure why CR will not be able to create a cross tab report with object as data source. Did you try creating a report with cross tab style?

Comment: Hi, THX for your help. The best understanding I got on this link http://www.blackbus.org/forum/crystal-reports/5438-question-regarding-how-i-can-generate-horizontal-crystal-report.html